# Mac terminal keeps giving message

Tags: macos, bash, terminal, directory

Whenever I open my terminal on my mac I get this message, `-bash: /usr/local/bin: is a directory`
How do I remove this? As I find it annoying and unneeded.

Comment: What's in your `~/.bash_profile`, `~/.profile`?

Comment: and also ~/.bashrc please

Comment: also check the terminal preferences. You can set up the terminal to run a command on launch.

Comment: How do I access those? And yes I've check my terminal preferences, but I don't see anything regarding my problem.

Answer (score 0):

There is probably a line trying to execute `/usr/local/bin` (which is a directory and not a executable) in either your `~/.bash_profile` or your `~/.bashrc`

If you want to view the contents of these files (as you asked above) you can type in your terminal after you open it:

`cat ~/.bash_profile`

and

`cat ~/.bashrc`

You can try to verify what lines mention `/usr/local/bin` by typing these commands:

`cat ~/.bash_profile | grep "/usr/local/bin"`

and

`cat ~/.bashrc | grep "/usr/local/bin"`